# Does there exist such a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Does there exist a nonzero $R$-module $M$ so that $M \cong M\oplus M$, where here $R$ is any ring with unity?

I'm not sure if this is true; I don't think it's true but I can't prove that. Clearly $M$ must be infinite for this to be true.

Comment: The trivial module

Answer (score 1):

One example is a vector space of infinite dimension $\kappa$, since the direct sum will have a basis of cardinality $\kappa + \kappa = \kappa$.

Comment: +1 (we can also replace "vector space" with "free $R$-module")

Comment: Is there any easier example you know of? This was intended to be a basic book problem after an introductory section on modules.